# openid and facebook authentication in webapp running on localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, openid, oauth-2.0

My java/javascript web application is in development, and I hava a javascript application that communicates with my database (where I maintain my own userids) using ajax POST commands to a servlet container running on localhost, within a vmware machine.  I want to be able to login using Google, Yahoo, and Facebook authentication, on this development setup, but in studying Facebook's OAuth 2.0 method, it looks like your web application has to hava a link to the facebook site, and provide a redirect link back to your own site when authentication is finished.  This method won't work because facebook can't redirect to a localhost address and reach my machine, which doesn't have a web presence.

Do I have the same issues with OpenID and Google/Yahoo authentication?

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook OAuth works with localhost apps. This is because Facebook redirects **the browser** to the `redirect_uri` you supply in oauth, your browser knows where `http://localhost` is (I actually used a virtual host in apache & windows vhosts,  don't know if you can enter localhost as website url in your app settings). Works perfectly

Google Oauth however, in my experience, doesn't work on local version. Somehow the site needed to be accessible from Google itself (not just the browser) for this to work, and it didn't, so it doesn't (I don't remember the exact details, sorry)

Don't know about the others

Answer (score 0):

You could add DNS entries on your local machine so that `mysite.com` resolves to your local computer.
By doing this, you will be able to login from your local machine to do your tests.

In Windows, you can do this by editing the file:
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Add a new line:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

Regarding OpenID, I am not sure if would accept logins from `localhost` URLs, but it will surely work after adding the entry in the hosts file and having a proper domain (even though it RESOLVES only on your computer).

The trick is that after login, Facebook or Google responds to your application with something like this: redirect the user to `mysite.com` as authenticated. Your browser then will resolve `mysite.com` as your machine and it is all working.