# Unable to create yahoo Application

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api

I am a web developer and I want to add a yahoo sign in for my website. I am currently developing website and running it on local host. When I am creating the Yahoo App it is not allowing to put the address in the URL. How should I proceed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site needs to be hosted on an externally facing location.  Localhost doesn't mean anything to yahoo.  It also looks like they won't let you enter just an IP address so they may require you to be on a domain.

If yahoo is going to be trusting you with user data they want you to be as legitimate as possible.

This SO question seems to have a workaround.  See the second answer. [openid and facebook authentication in webapp running on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268930/openid-and-facebook-authentication-in-webapp-running-on-localhost)

Comment: I have integrated with facebook and google with local host but dont know why yahoo does not allow it.

Comment: Different companies, different policies I guess.

Comment: See my last edit. Another question seems to explain how to circumvent this issue.